# How do I use a URL parameter from a response? Currently using Angular2/TypeScript

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm subscribing to a PUT response which gives me back a response containing a URL. I'd like to use that URL inside of my HTML, but I understand that might lead to XSS attacks. I've tried sanitizing it before it gets used, but it keeps prepending "localhost/" in front with the URL in double quotes. Code is below...

```
ngOnInit() {
  self._myService.getUrl(this.returnUrl).map(res => res.text())
    .subscribe(
      data => this.myLink = self.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(data),
      error => alert(error),
      () => console.log(this.myLink.toString())
    );
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a [href]="myLink">My Link</a>
```

The resulting link produces..

```
http://localhost/%22https://myexample.com/example.aspx?t=1418827d-71c7-4b26-b768-6f5612118fab%22
```

I would like the link to produce the URL as a link without "http://localhost/" before it. Any thoughts? Sorry for the newbish question.

Comment: Try with interpolation href={{myLink}}

Comment: When I try interpolation it appears as an unsafe link...

"unsafe:SafeValue must use [property]=binding: "https://myexample.com/example.aspx?t=1418827d-71c7-4b26-b768-6f5612118fab" (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)"

Comment: this.myLink = self.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(data).replace("http://localhost/") seems to me a quick but maybe not 'universal'

Comment: I guess I should update the question that "myLink" is a type of SafeUrl. The replace function doesn't exist off of that type. I tried replacing it in "data" inside, but it still shows the same thing :/. Thanks though!

Comment: @CaptainHammer Did you get the solution for this?